# Going to a specific frame on key press

Tags: actionscript-2, keyboard-events

I am trying to jump from any timeline's point to frame 16, but I'm not sure about the code and the place where it should be. At the moment I have this code in frame 1 on a seprate layer.

```
cheat = new Object();
cheat.onKeyDown = function() {
    if (KEY.getCode() == Key.SPACE) {
        gotoAndStop(16);
    }
}

key.addListener(cheat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You committed these mistakes:

```
KEY.getCode()          // KEY in capital letters
key.addListener(cheat) // key in lowercase letters
```

**The Key class**

By convention all the classes begin with a capital letter. The correct spelling for the Key class is `Key`.

**The correct code**

```
var keyListener:Object = new Object();

keyListener.onKeyDown = function():Void {
    if (Key.getCode() == Key.SPACE) {
        gotoAndStop(16);
    }
}

Key.addListener(keyListener);
```